# The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount. How can I solve this?

Tags: paypal

Paypal Shows me the following error when I submit this form:
The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount.

I tried it with all the means possible but couldn't solve it. Please help me someone.

How can I solve this?

```
<form action="
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
" method="post" name="psubmit" id="psubmit">
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="_25_259_0_58__" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="neo@ibacs.co.uk" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://etakeout.co.uk/orders/wait" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://etakeout.co.uk/" />
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://etakeout.co.uk/" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://etakeout.co.uk/orders/ipn_handler" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="inetfoods" />
<input type="hidden" name="mrb" value="R-6C7952342H795591R" />
<input type="hidden" name="pal" value="9E82WJBKKGPLQ" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="asf" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="asfas" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="asdfasf" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Alcester" />
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="CF 245" />
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="GB" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="neo@ibacs.co.uk" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="0.00" />


<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Starter - New Base Item español -  Chicken==1.5 pizza" />

<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="2" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="5.985" />

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Delivery Cost" />

<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="4.00" />

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="CC Fee" />

<input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="7.00" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are having
`<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="5.985" />`

It should be `<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="5.98" />` Because PayPal accept up to 2 place of decimals.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're sending '5.985' GBP. That's not a correct amount.
Change this to '5.98' and try again.